# The criteria to determine file status in Git

Tags: git

I summarize the following criterias:

> Committed = Stored in *.git* directory.
>
> Modified = Changed since checked out, but not in the staging area.
>
> Staged = Modified and put into the staging area.
>
> Tracked = ???
>
> Untracked = ???

But I don't know how to decide a file as tracked or untracked. I guess there must be some kind of **tracked file collection** to search for. Though it seems *so natural* that a newly created file is considered by Git as untracked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a formal definition, but if you consider tracked as being in HEAD, than that means that the file was tracked in your previous commit.  If you consider a file tracked if it is in the index, than the file is tracked as soon as you add or remove it from the index.

Here is how you see all files currently being tracked in HEAD
`git ls-tree HEAD^{tree} -r`

If you consider tracked as *only* needing to be in the index you can view tracked files with
`git ls-files`

Comment: Many people class a file as "tracked" as soon as it is added to the index whether or not it is in `HEAD`.

Comment: So, what's HEAD? I have seen this a lot but my textbook hasn't mentioned it *yet*. Could you just give me some *forecast*? ;)

Comment: @Charles I suppose I could see it either way.  If you look at it that way `git ls-files` will show you what is tracked

Comment: Thanks Andy. As you said "...but if you consider tracked as being in HEAD..." In fact, I don't know what *being tracked* means. And I just want to know how Git decide a file as untracked.

Comment: I don't think git has a formal definition for "tracked", as you can see by the differing opinions from Charles and manojlds.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked, by popular usage, is synonymous to committed.

Untracked, is something that has not been committed. So for example a file just added to the working directory is untracked. And again, by popular definition, even something that is added to the index / staged is considered untracked as long as it has not been committed.